# How does the amount of water in a cylindrical can affect its motion when rolling down an inclined plane?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I’m conducting research on how the volume of water in a cylindrical can affect its motion (acceleration, velocity etc) when rolling down an inclined plane.

However, I’m unsure what physics concepts would be involved in describing the results that I obtain.

Comment: what results are you obtaining?